# Probability for same amount of hits.

Tags: probability

I have this puzzle of probability:

> Joe and Mike each have 4 apples. After they've eaten all their apples
>   they started to throw apple core in to the recycle bin for accuracy.
>   Joe's accuracy is 0.4 and Mike's 0.6. What is the probability that Joe
>   and Mike get the same amount of hits?

Now where should I begin? How is this probability calculated?

Comment: A brute force approach would simply be to sum the probabilities of every case where they get an even amount of hits.

Comment: How many cores does an apple have? 2?

Comment: @zoli One of course :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Split it into disjoint events, and then sum up their probabilities:**

- The probability that each one of them hits ${\color\red0}$ times is:

$$\binom4{\color\red0}\cdot0.4^{\color\red0}\cdot(1-0.4)^{4-{\color\red0}}\cdot\binom4{\color\red0}\cdot0.6^{\color\red0}\cdot(1-0.6)^{4-{\color\red0}}$$

- The probability that each one of them hits ${\color\red1}$ time is:

$$\binom4{\color\red1}\cdot0.4^{\color\red1}\cdot(1-0.4)^{4-{\color\red1}}\cdot\binom4{\color\red1}\cdot0.6^{\color\red1}\cdot(1-0.6)^{4-{\color\red1}}$$

- The probability that each one of them hits ${\color\red2}$ times is:

$$\binom4{\color\red2}\cdot0.4^{\color\red2}\cdot(1-0.4)^{4-{\color\red2}}\cdot\binom4{\color\red2}\cdot0.6^{\color\red2}\cdot(1-0.6)^{4-{\color\red2}}$$

- The probability that each one of them hits ${\color\red3}$ times is:

$$\binom4{\color\red3}\cdot0.4^{\color\red3}\cdot(1-0.4)^{4-{\color\red3}}\cdot\binom4{\color\red3}\cdot0.6^{\color\red3}\cdot(1-0.6)^{4-{\color\red3}}$$

- The probability that each one of them hits ${\color\red4}$ times is:

$$\binom4{\color\red4}\cdot0.4^{\color\red4}\cdot(1-0.4)^{4-{\color\red4}}\cdot\binom4{\color\red4}\cdot0.6^{\color\red4}\cdot(1-0.6)^{4-{\color\red4}}$$

---

Overall, the probability that each one of them hits an equal number of times is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{4}\binom4n\cdot0.4^n\cdot(1-0.4)^{4-n}\cdot\binom4n\cdot0.6^n\cdot(1-0.6)^{4-n}=23.22432\%$$

Comment: Cool, the answer is correct! Thank you!